# Blender opening with a scene I have deleted

Tags: customization

I have a pretty annoying problem. Every time I quit and reopen blender it always opens as this scene.[image]

But when I go to a new scene it opens as this:
[image]

I have tried everything. Saving the startup file, Reinstalling blender and even restarting my computer but nothing seems to have worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried deleting the startup file to let Blender recreate it by itself, or even Blender's whole config directory? I'm not sure where those would be located on a Mac, but somewhere in your home directory. On my system (FreeBSD running Blender 2.77) it's ${HOME}/.config/blender/2.77. Perhaps you'll be able to deduce the location on your system from that. If you delete the entire config directory, you'll of course lose all your customisations, and I hope someone has a better solution.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked even though I lost my plugins it was worth it. I can get them again.

Comment: You're welcome. I won't add it as an answer for the time being, as it really is a last resort, and I can't explain why this problem occured in the first place. I've gone through the user preferences to see if I could find some setting that might cause this, but I didn't. Perhaps a buggy add-on. Anyway, if nothing better comes along, I may add this an answer later.

Comment: What is that other scene? All you say is that you deleted it. Can you give more details? When did you delete it? How did you delete it? Where was the .blend file stored?

Comment: I deleted it by putting it in the trash and emptying it. Sorry, I didn't know there was another way to delete a file.

Comment: For future reference, Blender's config folder on Mac is in `~/Library/Application Support/Blender`. (Don't just copy that path, I used a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).)